# Stop Callback While Function Still Performing Task

Tags: javascript, animation, audio, callback, settimeout

Question: Can a function ignore a callback, stopping it from firing again, while it’s currently performing a task it was previously executed to do?

I have two functions. **Function #1** triggers an audio file using `setTimeout` with a callback to itself. It uses `Math.round(Math.random() * aStartMax) + aStartMin;` to fire the sound in a loop at somewhat randomized times. **Function #2** performs a visual animation that takes a certain amount of time to complete. Currently, whenever a sound is triggered by function #1, a callback executes function #2 which performs the visual animation. The problem arises in that function #1 fires off sounds with a greater frequency than it takes for the function #2 animation to complete, causing the animation to jump back to its start (it looks glitchy). I don’t want to slow down the function #1 firing frequency, I simply would like function #2 to ignore the callbacks that it receives if it is already running. Is this possible? That way sounds can fire with any frequency, but the visual animation will only be executed if it is currently not in motion.

```
// FUNCTION #1: Audio function
(function loop() { 

    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * aStartMax) + aStartMin;

    setTimeout(function() {
        playDuration = Math.floor((Math.random() * aPlayDurationMax) + aPlayDurationMin);

        setTimeout(function () { 
            var sound = new Howl({
                src: [soundFileName], 
                autoplay: true,
                loop: true,
                volume: (Math.random() * 0.8) + aVolumeMin,
                fade: 0 
            });

            var id2 = sound.play(); 
            sound.fade(0, 1, aFadeIn, id2)
            {
                do_the_thing($('.a')); // << callback for function #2
            };

            setTimeout(function () {
                sound.fade(1, 0, aFadeOut, id2); 
            }, playDuration);

        }, aWaitToPlay);

        loop(); // calls the audio function to execute again
    }, rand);  
}());

// FUNCTION #2: Visual function
function do_the_thing($elements) {
   var delay = $elements.children().length * universalBoxTime; 
   setTimeout(function() {
        $elements.makisu('toggle');
        $elements.makisu({ 
            selector: 'dd',
            overlap: .7,
            speed: 2
        });
    }, 0);
}
```

I’ve read that I can set up my #2 function with `setTimeout` like this below. But I don’t think that will allow the function to ignore/drop new callbacks, but rather, it will simply cue them up so they will fire at a later time?

```
function yourfoo() {
// code
setTimeout(yourfoo, 3000);
}

setTimeout(yourfoo, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the state of callback function 2 in a variable if it is running. If it is, do not execute it. If it is not, execute it. Check the pseudo code below

```
var isRunning = false;

if(!isRunning) {
   // callback function 2
}

function callback2() {
// execute it
isRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: If you are able to roughly plug my code into your function, that would be most helpful. I've been trying a number of variations for a few days, but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can store whether the function (or it's callback) is still running by storing that information on itself. I'm not sure exactly when function #2 is done (maybe after `delay` elapses?), but here's an example:

```
function do_the_thing() {

    if ( do_the_thing.running ) return;
    do_the_thing.running = true;

    // your code

    setTimeout( () => do_the_thing.running = false, 1000 );

}
```

This will make it so the actual function body in `do_the_thing` executes a max of once a second. Ideally you would set `do_the_thing.running = false` when `do_the_thing` is actually done executing.

Comment: If you are able to roughly plug my code into your function, that would be most helpful. I've been trying a number of variations for a few days, but can't get it to work.